# windows phone- background thread takes more time while working with web services

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker

My app consumes web services.Whenever I am making a call to the server, I create a background thread, call a custom control for displaying progress bar and blocking user action, then display results using dispatcher and removing the progress bar.Also note that I am making an async call with a background worker to the web service using HTTP client.I find that using **background thread takes 2 or 3 seconds more to load** than calling the web service directly from UI thread.

1. How can I reduce the extra loading time due to use of background threads?Can setting a thread priority resolve the issue?
2. In case we are creating a background thread, it is used exclusively for the operation that we are coding it to,So what is the advantage of making an async call inside a background thread?
3. Is it okay to call web services from UI thread only, as anyways user is blocked from taking any action while using background thread to make a service call?

Comment: How do you create a background thread exactly?

Comment: @Stilgar private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();bw.RunWorkerAsync();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is impossible to tell without more information. It shouldn't take signidicantly more. Setting a thread priority is hardly the correct thing to do.
2. There is no advantage to making async call inside a dedicated thread
3. No you can't do that. It is bad and you won't even pass certification.

Consider using async/await and Tasks to accomplish your goal. While the performance difference you are seeing is definitely strange and should not happen async/await and Tasks are easier to use (no dispatcher for example) and you can find your bug gone just by virtue of having cleaner code.

Comment: You mean to say there is no need for a dispatcher?

Comment: There is no need for dispatcher if you use async/await otherwise there is need for dispatcher. Awaited calls on the UI thread will automatically dispatch to the UI thread after the call is complete.